# How should I denote vectors and matrices in equations when accessing contents within in a scientific paper?

Tags: notation, vectors, matrix-equations, article-writing

I come mainly from a software background and my math is not as strong as my programming. I am writing a paper and cover the basics of neural networks. As an example, here is what I have in terms of some equations:

$$ 
  n_j^{(\ell)} = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\ell-1}} a_i^{(\ell-1)} w_{ij}^{(\ell)} + b_j^{(\ell)}, \quad
j=1, 2, \ldots, N_\ell. $$

Here, $w_{ij}$ accesses a matrix which I introduce alone as $W$ earlier. My question is should I change the format depending on what is returned? For example, $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector and I access a scalar at $b_j$, so I print it in italics as opposed to bold. Is this correct? I apologise the question is somewhat open, I am new to this!

Comment: Your convention seems pretty good and I've seen it used in many places before but I'd say there is no universaly accepted standard for this type of notation in Math. The best attitude if of course to clearly explain your notation at the beginning and stick to it throughout the paper.

Comment: Thank you, @Ruy. I would mark this as solved!